# Gson conversion to Json with two date format is not working

Tags: java, json, date, datetime, gson

I have two date formats which are from server `Json` . **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss** and **yyyy-MM-dd** are my date formats.

So I tried to convert this `Json` to `Gson` with following codes.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

These are my date formats,

```
private static final String[] DATE_FORMATS = new String[] {
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd"
};

private class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

     @Override
     public Date deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
          for (String format : DATE_FORMATS) {
                try {
                  return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).parse(jsonElement.getAsString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                }
          }
          throw new JsonParseException("Unparseable date: \"" + jsonElement.getAsString()
                    + "\". Supported formats: " + Arrays.toString(DATE_FORMATS));
      }       

}
```

**Update**

This is my `Json` object,

```
{
  "idpatient": 56,
  "diabetesType": null,
  "language": null,
  "customId": "CUS790",
  "diabetesOther": null,
  "firstName": "Niro",
  "lastName": "Wije",
  "email": "sahirml@gmail.com",
  "dob": "1989-10-11",
  "parentEmail": null,
  "gender": "male",
  "diagnosedDate": "2016-11-11",
  "height": 0,
  "weight": 0,
  "heightUnit": null,
  "weightUnit": null,
  "theme": "Lite",
  "userName": "weera",
  "password": "asdf9999",
  "dateCreated": 1478880594000,
  "lastUpdated": 1478880594000
}
```

Then I tried to convert a Json object to Gson object by using this. I got following error log.

```
11-11 16:11:17.735 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unparseable date: "1478880594000". Supported formats: [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd]
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at my.api.example.activities.LoginActivity$DateDeserializer.deserialize(LoginActivity.java:180)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at my.api.example.activities.LoginActivity$DateDeserializer.deserialize(LoginActivity.java:168)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall.access$100(OkHttpCall.java:29)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:94)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-11 16:11:17.755 28072-28072/my.api.example D/LOGIN_ACTIVITY:  ERROR_MESSAGE Unparseable date: "1478880594000". Supported formats: [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd]
```

It means this method is not working for my date formats.
How could I handle this exception ?

Have any ideas ?

Comment: Convert jsonElement.getAsString() to a formatted date as registered first

Comment: paste json here for better understanding.

Comment: @satendra : Please look at updated post.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error, you shared the server is returning date in
Milliseconds and not the format your expected.

com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Unparseable date: "1478880594000". Supported formats: [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, yyyy-MM-dd].

First you need to convert to Date, then format as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

update this line

```
return new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US).format(new Date(jsonElement));
```

hope this will work.

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, I can see that you are not passing `java.util.Date`, but a timestamp (long) and you are registering type adapter for `java.util.Date` class.